# std::move with std::make_pair

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, move

Is there any difference between:

```
std::map <int,std::pair<T,T>> m;
T t1,t2;
m.emplace(1,std::make_pair(t1,t2));
```

and:

```
std::map <int,std::pair<T,T>> m;
T t1,t2;
m.emplace(1,std::move(std::make_pair(t1,t2)));
```

Is the `std::move` redundant here? Will `std::map::emplace` and `perfect forwarding` take care of allocating the `std::pair` directly in the `std::map`?

Comment: There are two `std::pair`s involved here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::make_pair(...)` and `std::move(std::make_pair(...))` are both rvalue expressions (the first one is a prvalue, the second one is an xvalue). Since `emplace` takes forwarding references, both are deduced as the same type, so `std::move` in this case is redundant, but in a general case, a redundant `std::move` can inhibit copy-elision.

```
m.emplace(1, std::make_pair(t1, t2));
```

is equivalent to:

```
auto&& arg = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
std::pair<const int, std::pair<T, T>> e(1, std::forward<std::pair<T, T>>(arg));
```

which performs the following initialization of the map element's value:

```
auto&& arg = std::make_pair(t1, t2);
std::pair<T, T> p(std::forward<std::pair<T, T>>(arg));
```

Note that this is different from:

```
std::pair<T, T> p(t1, t2);
```

The former first creates a prvalue pair (makes copies of `t1` and `t2`), which is then moved from (moves both the copied `t1` and `t2` into `p`). No copy-elision takes place.

The latter uses `t1` and `t2` to initialize both `T`s stored in the pair.

To avoid the unnecessary move resulting from the first syntax, you can instead utilize piecewise construction:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct
        , std::forward_as_tuple(1)
        , std::forward_as_tuple(t1, t2));
```

that will be equivalent to:

```
auto&& arg = std::tuple<T&, T&>(t1, t2);
std::pair<T, T> p(std::get<0>(std::forward<std::tuple<T&, T&>>(arg))
                , std::get<1>(std::forward<std::tuple<T&, T&>>(arg)));
```

that will initialize the elements of the pair from reference members bound to original `t1` and `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair(t1,t2)));
```

will call move constructor.

Comment: Better to use piecewise construction in this case, which will result in no moves *or* copies.