# How to efficiently insert a pair in std::vector?

Tags: c++, int, std, move, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<std::pair<...>>` and want to efficiently modify them:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(4, 5);
vec.emplace_back(6, 7);

// Now I want to set the first pair in the vector.
vec[0] = make_pair(10, 10);
```

As I understand we have

1. Temporary pair is constructed by `make_pair`. This takes 2 copies of `int`s.
2. Next `pair<int,int>& operator=( pair<int,int>&& other )` is called which calls `std::move` on two `int`s in the `pair`. This takes 2 copies of `int`s.

As a result we 4 copies of ints!

But modification of a `pair` in a `Vector` should take 2 copies of `int`s. `emplace_back` seems to be what I need, but it makes an in-place construction only in the end of the vector, not at any other index.

For sure I can do

```
vec[0].first = 10;
vec[0].second = 10;
```

But this takes into account the internals of pair, which I want to omit.

How can I write the code more efficiently (without redundant copies of `int`s)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906575/stdmove-with-stdmake-pair

Comment: A move of a pair of ints will have the same performance as a copy of a pair of ints.  FWIW.

Comment: Unless you can measure a problem, I would not worry about a few ints. Is this inside a huge loop?

Comment: FYI, `std::pair` has a constructor that takes the two values as input, so you can omit the `make_pair()` when calling `emplace_back()`: `vec.emplace_back(4, 5);`

Comment: I suppose that this code works in a performance critical loop. emplace_back adds an element to the end, but I need to modify an element in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Enable compiler optimization and behold, they are exactly the same: https://godbolt.org/z/Nwb_y0

The assembly generated by GCC 8 is:

```
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], esi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax+4], edx
```

As you can see, the integers are stored just once, there is no extra copy.

If you compile with `-O1` instead of `-O2` or `-O3`, the code is actually worse for the "simpler" version without `make_pair`: it loads the address from the vector twice.  So the `make_pair` version is better at `-O1` and identical at higher levels of optimization.

Comment: Thank you! https://godbolt.org is a good place for exploring compiled code!